# angular 2 rc - Cannot read property 'request' of undefined

Tags: angular, request

This is my code and I couldn't figure out nor find a solution for my problem. I am sorry if the answer exists somewhere and couldn't find it.

This is the app.component.ts file

```js
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/http';
import {SimpleHTTPComponent} from './simplehttp'


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS],
  template: `
    <div>
      <simple-http></simple-http>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: [SimpleHTTPComponent]
})
export class AppComponent {
 
 data: Object;
 loading: boolean;
 constructor() {
   }
}
```

This is my simplehttp.ts file

```js
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/http';
import {Inject} from '@angular/core'


@Component({
selector: 'simple-http',
template: `
 <h2>Basic Request</h2>
 <button type="button" (click)="makeRequest()">Make Request</button>
 <div *ngIf="loading">loading...</div>
 <pre>{{data | json}}</pre>`,
providers:[HTTP_PROVIDERS]
})
export class SimpleHTTPComponent {
 data: Object;
 loading: boolean;
 http: Http;
 constructor( @Inject(Http) private _http: Http){
  
 }
 makeRequest():void{
  this.loading = true;
  this.http.request('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
  .subscribe((res: Response) => {
  this.data = res.json();
  this.loading = false;
  });
 }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three is no need to provide `HTTP_PROVIDERS` more than once

Your code has a bug. You're injecting to `_http` but use `http`

```ts
export class SimpleHTTPComponent {
    data: Object;
    loading: boolean;
    http: Http;

    // injects to local variable `_http`
    constructor( @Inject(Http) private _http: Http){}

    makeRequest():void{
        this.loading = true;
        // uses local variable `http` (without `_`)
        this.http.request('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
        .subscribe((res: Response) => {
        this.data = res.json();
        this.loading = false;
        });
    }
}
```

It should be like

```ts
export class SimpleHTTPComponent {
    data: Object;
    loading: boolean;

    constructor( @Inject(Http) private _http: Http){

    }
    makeRequest():void{
        this.loading = true;
        this._http.request('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
        .subscribe((res: Response) => {
        this.data = res.json();
        this.loading = false;
        });
    }
}
```

If the constructor parameter has the access modifier `private` or `public` then this also automatically declares an instance property.

Comment: You are fast, I was about to write same answer.+1 from me :)

Comment: The early bird gets the worm ;-)

Comment: Thank you, I know I've been making stupid mistakes somewhere.

Comment: @Priyesh Kumar, Gunter is always quick in posting answers and comments 